# How to add "0b" in front of an integer to convert from binary to base 10

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert the integer 1101 in binary to 13 in decimal. I can do:

```
0b1101.to_s(10) # => 13
```

How would I take 1101 and add the `"0b"` to the front? Is that possible?

Comment: `0b1101` is just another way to write `13`. In other words: `0b1101` already is `13`. Calling `to_s` will just convert it to a string, i.e. `"13"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you're trying to do this should work

```
Integer("1101", 2) # => 13
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add anything to the string. Just call `#to_i` on it with the desired base as a parameter:

```
"1101".to_i(2) # => 13
```